# how can i package spring mvc application to jar?

Tags: java, maven

I have an application built using `maven` and `spring mvc` and `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. Can I package these to a jar file, so that i can run the jar file to start a tomcat server?

That means i don't need tomcat, only a jar file can provide a web service.

Comment: you want to package your app  and  tomcat in one jar ?

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring documentation is your friend. I am providing the links which you can follow, with highlighted parts in this post.

[Spring Boot Maven Packaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging)

Once spring-boot-maven-plugin has been included in your `pom.xml` it will automatically attempt to rewrite archives to make them executable using the `spring-boot:repackage` goal. You should configure your project to build a jar or war (as appropriate) using the usual packaging element in the `pom.xml`

The main class that you want to launch can either be specified using a configuration option, or by adding a `Main-Class` attribute to the manifest in the usual way.

To build and run a project artifact, you can type the following:

```
$ mvn package 
$ java -jar target/mymodule-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

More information about the plugin is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.5.RELEASE/maven-plugin/)