# Package Spring web project into jar (uber-jar) without spring boot (non spring-boot project)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle

I have read through some tutorials,

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin

I also saw people asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872994/how-can-i-package-spring-mvc-application-to-jar), but it is using Maven, I tried to use Gradle, but it doesn't work.

I can't really get it works in non Spring-boot project, so my question is, is it possible to package uber-jar in non Spring boot project?

My Spring project is normal MVC project, built by Gradle, is there any Gradle plugin can fulfill my objective? Or actually the Spring-boot plugin can do it on non Spring-boot project?

Comment: Please elaborate why do you want to do that?

Comment: @ZakiAnwarHamdani I like the spring-boot uber-jar package function, but our web app right now is normal spring-mvc project which I am not allowed to convert it to spring-boot. And I need to pass the jar file to non-IT people to test who doesn't install tomcat or any standalone server. It is nice if they can just issue command to executable jar with embedable java container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `embedded tomcat` to do that works. May be this article will help you [Create a Java Web Application Using Embedded Tomcat](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat)
And here is my TomcatBootstrap code

```
public class TomcatBootstrap {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TomcatBootstrap.class);
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip", "*.jar");
    int port =Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("server.port", "8080"));
    String contextPath = System.getProperty("server.contextPath", "");
    String docBase = System.getProperty("server.docBase", getDefaultDocBase());
    LOG.info("server port : {}, context path : {},doc base : {}",port, contextPath, docBase);
    Tomcat tomcat = createTomcat(port,contextPath, docBase);
    tomcat.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                tomcat.stop();
            } catch (LifecycleException e) {
                LOG.error("stoptomcat error.", e);
            }
        }
    });
    tomcat.getServer().await();
}

private static String getDefaultDocBase() {
    File classpathDir = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(".").getFile());
    File projectDir =classpathDir.getParentFile().getParentFile();
    return new File(projectDir,"src/main/webapp").getPath();
}
private static Tomcat createTomcat(int port,String contextPath, String docBase) throws Exception{
    String tmpdir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setBaseDir(tmpdir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(tmpdir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAutoDeploy(false);
    tomcat.getHost().setDeployOnStartup(false);
    tomcat.getEngine().setBackgroundProcessorDelay(-1);
    tomcat.setConnector(newNioConnector());
    tomcat.getConnector().setPort(port);
    tomcat.getService().addConnector(tomcat.getConnector());
    Context context =tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, docBase);
    StandardServer server =(StandardServer) tomcat.getServer();
    //APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html
    server.addLifecycleListener(new AprLifecycleListener());
    //Prevent memory leaks due to use of particularjava/javax APIs
    server.addLifecycleListener(new JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener());
    return tomcat;
}

private static Connector newNioConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    Http11NioProtocol protocol =(Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
    return connector;
}

}
```